# ValueError: Shapes (10000, 11) and (10000, 1) are incompatible Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've seen this error, however, I'm unsure how to fix it in my case. 
My repo for all the code and dataset: https://github.com/itisyeetimetoday/reggression

```
regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
            label_dimension=11,
            hidden_units=hidden_layers,
            model_dir=MODEL_PATH,
            dropout=dropout,
            config=test_config,
            activation_fn = tf.nn.relu,
            optimizer  = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
```

However, the above line generates this error: ValueError: Shapes (10000, 11) and (10000, 1) are incompatible

Technically, the fit line is getting the error, but the model parameters that can solve the error. I've tried changing the dimensions to 10 in case TensorFlow starts at 0, but this didn't work. How do I fix the error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ValueError: Shapes (batch, 11) and (batch, 1) are incompatible
```

Error indicates that the model expects output shape to be (10000, 11) whereas the true label shape is (10000, 1). So, You have to change the `label_dimension=1`.

```
regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns,
            label_dimension=1,
            hidden_units=hidden_layers,
            model_dir=MODEL_PATH,
            dropout=dropout,
            config=test_config,
            activation_fn = tf.nn.relu,
            optimizer  = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
```

**In case of 11 output nodes**, you should change the dimension of your training dataset label from 1 to 11.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The current probably is that(if you download the repo) you can see that the shape of both the training and the label dataset is [11000], so the fact that TensorFlow reads the labels as 10000 is a problem.  I'm also trying to create a DNN regressor with 11 input variables and 11 output variables so changing label_dimension=1 would mean that I would have 11 input variables and 1 output variables, which is not what I want.

Comment: After changing `label_dimension=1` in your code, it worked and only then i posted the answer. And FYI, both X_train and y_train have a shape of `(109999, 1)` as your nn_inputs.csv and nn_outputs.csv file have only 1 column (as per your code).

Comment: To make it work for 11 outputs and 11 input feature column(multi-modal regression) both of your feature vector and labels should have a dimension of 11. Just to test you can use dummy values of X and y like follows: X = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 11)) y = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 11)) and keep the label_dimension=1.